# page overlay(gray out) does not extend full length

Tags: html, css

example issue
https://www.primaryself.com/indextest.php

To reproduce, click on one of the "Book" buttons.

This overlays the page with a grey out layer, and a window on top of that.
The grey out layer does not extend the full way down when displayed on a small computer window or a mobile device.
The smaller the window is made, the less it covers. it appears to be some sort of % issue

[image]

Thanks in advance

Was expecting layer to go all the way to the bottom of the page

Comment: Please extract just enough of the HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem and put it into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your “grey-out” layer needs to have fixed positioning instead of absolute positioning:

```
.overlay::after {
  position: fixed;
}
```